# Flask not working on Kubernetes (GKE) Load balancer IP address

Tags: flask, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have been playing around with deploying a simple Flask app on Kubernetes (GKE).

However, when I go to the LoadBalancer IP address the Flask site is not loading and is throwing the following error: 'Connection refused by the server'

What i have done:

- Built a simple flask app that runs on port 5000 and deployed it to a docker container on Container Registry
- I then deployed the app in a pod on GKE with command: *kubectl run site --image=gcr.io/<>/site-image-test --port=5000 --env="NAME=Will"  -- bin/sh -c 'python3 main.py'*
- Checking the pod logs, the app/pod is running as expected
- I then created a loadbalancer service with command: *kubectl expose pod site --port=8080 --target-port=5000 --type=LoadBalancer*
- The service is listed as running:

...but when I go to the service IP address in my browser the flask page is not loading.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong, given that everything seems to be working fine?

**UPDATE**
Including screenshot of service accounts gotten from kubectl:

[image]

Comment: Do  you use the correct port? 8080 in your browser?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, yes

Comment: Can you share your kubectl service list?

Comment: hi @guillaumeblaquiere have added above to main description. thanks

Comment: Have you any security? filter?

Comment: If you exec into pod and do a curl localhost. Do you get error or not?

Comment: kubectl exec -it POD -- sh, to install curl apk add --no-cache curl or apt-get install curl

Comment: It's possible that you may need to create a fw rule to allow access, although I don't think you should have to.  You might want to try exposing your app on port 80 rather than 8080 just as a quick test.

Comment: @2bon2b Try by setting up the cluster context. To set the cluster context use the command below: **gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME**. Refer to the [Link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#connection_refused) below. To understand the issue further please provide the error screen shot or full error.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `kubectl get service site -o yaml` make sure that the IP you are connecting to is the one listed under, LoadBalancer.ingress

Relevant documentation:

- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps